# Cannot get custom document ID in Couchbase Lite - Android

Tags: java, android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I'm new in Couchbase Android. I use Couchbase Lite v1.1.0 to save my data local. But I facing with some problems when to do that. I googled, read document in Couchbase Lite and find all post in stackoverflow but I still not understand what I facing.

Here is my snippet demo code to save my data in database with custom id of document is index **i**:

```
cbManager=new Manager(new AndroidContext(context),
                    Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
cbDatabase=cbManager.getDatabase("my_db");
                 .....

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
   Document document=cbDatabase.getDocument(String.valueOf(i)); // This line I custom document with id i
   Map<String,Object> docContent= new HashMap<String, Object>();
   docContent.put("title", title);
   docContent.put("firstName", firstName);
   docContent.put("lastName", lastName);
   try{
       document.putProperties(docContent);
   } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e){
       Log.e(TAG, "Cannot write document to database", e);
     }
}
```

And get all datas from Couchbase Lite:

```
 Query allDocumentsQuery= cbDatabase.createAllDocumentsQuery();
 QueryEnumerator queryResult=allDocumentsQuery.run();
 for (Iterator<QueryRow> it=queryResult;it.hasNext();){
      QueryRow row=it.next();
      
      Document doc=row.getDocument();
      String id=doc.getId(); // I get the id in here but the result is the default id (UUID):(
 }
```

So, I have two questions:

1. When I query all documents from database (couchbase lite), the document is returned which the default id (UUID), Why it is not return my custom ID?

   ( *means: Saving all the document to database which custom ids: 1, 2, 3 ......9. But the result of all documents when get from database have default ids: UUID, UUID,..., UUID.* )
2. I dont understand Why I save the document in order but the return of all documents are not in order ? (because this reason make me custom id of document)

Please give me some advises or guide me on the best way to do this. Thank you all so much.

Comment: Are you able to retrieve the documents you created with the custom ID? What I mean is, are you to execute for example:

Document document = database.getDocument("custom_id");

Comment: oops, I try and I cannot. Why?

Comment: It means your document has not been saved with the id you provided. It was saved with a generated uuid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the _rev property to your map with the id as value.

Here's an excerpt from the [documentation](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/document/document/index.html):

```
 putProperties(Map<String, Object> properties)
Creates and saves a new Revision with the specified properties. To succeed the specified properties must include a '_rev' property whose value maches the current Revision's id.
```

So your code should look like this:

```
Map<String,Object> docContent= new HashMap<String, Object>();
docContent.put("_rev", String.valueOf(i));
docContent.put("title", title);
docContent.put("firstName", firstName);
docContent.put("lastName", lastName);
```